# Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using google firebase, but when I want to `async` data from firebase that showing this error for me.

**shop.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="danger">
        <ion-title>商城</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="common-bg">
    <!-- slider on top-->
    <ion-slides pager autoplay="2000">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
        <img src="{{ slide.src }}" alt="">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>

    <h4 text-center>这里是商品</h4>

    <!--List of items-->
    <ion-grid class="list-cards">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6 class="product" (click)="viewItem(item.id)">
          <div class="card light-bg">
            <img src="assets/img/logo2.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="price" text-center>RM100</div>
            <!-- <div class="price" text-center>{{ item.price | currency:'USD':true }}</div> -->
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item-group *ngFor="let contact of contactsList | async">
        <ion-item>
          {{contact.$value}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-item-group>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-row> 
        <ion-col col-6>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Contact" placeholder="添加评论"></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="addContact()">评论</button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
```

**shop.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirebaseServiceProvider } from '../../providers/firebase-service/firebase-service';
import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-shop',
  templateUrl: 'shop.html',
})
export class ShopPage {

  contactsList:AngularFireList<any>;
  Contact = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public actionctrl:ActionSheetController,
    public firebaseService:FirebaseServiceProvider) {
      this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList();
  }

  addContact() {
    this.firebaseService.addContact(this.Contact);
  }

  public slides = [
    {
      src: 'assets/img/slide_1.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'assets/img/slide_3.jpg'
    }
  ];

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ShopPage');
  }

}
```

UPDATE CODE:

**firebase-service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Injectable()
export class FirebaseServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,public angularfiredb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log('Hello FirebaseServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getContactsList() {
    return this.angularfiredb.list('/contactsList/');
  }

  addContact(name) {
    this.angularfiredb.list('/contactsList').push(name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use |async pipe only over an observable, remove the pipe

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let contact of contactsList">
```

**EDIT**

Change your method inside the service as

```
getContactsList() {
    return this.angularfiredb.list('contactsList').valueChanges();
  }
```

and the component as

```
this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList().subscribe(contacts=> {
      this.contactsList = contacts;
});
```

Comment: After I remove the pipe.. showing new error for me 'Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.'

Comment: it seems this.contactsList  is not an array. post what you have

Comment: I just want to get data from firebase that got data already...so what should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273317/how-to-display-angularfirestore-data/48273933#48273933

Comment: Could you help me change my code? That answer not quit same with this one.

Comment: can you post your service too

Comment: Your component means 'shop.ts' right? still showing error for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163371/discussion-between-yuyang-he-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: error : You can not assign the type Subscription to the type AngularFireList <any>. 
The attribute "query" is missing in the type "Subscription".

Comment: i think you have missed some code, there is no code part